# Have there been recent changes to login?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

After having been logged in for months on my Mac/Safari, twice within the last two days I've been greeted by the "Welcome to the Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" message and had to re-login.  I **never** click the *log out* button, nor have I cleared my cookies.  Have there been recent changes that might explain this?  Will it continue?

**Update**: I remain logged on at work (Win7/IE8), despite having to re-login twice at home.

Comment: same thing happened to me a day or two ago

Comment: I've also had this issue the in the past 2 days

Answer (score 1):

No changes to login, no other reports of this problem.

Comment: Except, apparently, from @Otaku and @Nick Craver as reported in comments to the question.

Comment: Yeah. I was working as normal, clicked to go to another page and all of a sudden had the login screen show up. Another weird thing that happened was when I logged in, it said something like "*Your account as been automatically associated with two other sites*" and then upon following the link it showed me the association with SuperUser and Meta. I had already associated those before though. I just accepted it and moved on...but it was so bizarre I went outside and had a smoke.

Comment: Heads up - I just got kicked out again, will try clearing cookies, but this is definitely a recent thing, whatever the cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cookie, it has an expiration date. I estimate it is one year starting from your last real login.

Comment: I just checked and it appears to use a sliding expiration (as expected) as the times on the cookie after a later request have increased.  Besides, I logged in yesterday and it happened again today.  FWIW, it looks like the cookie window is 6 months, not 12.

Comment: @tvanosson: you're right, the cookie is updated on every page reload. Maybe you should try deleting the cookie and then logging in again